# KVM access via ipmitool

Tags: user-management, console, keyboard-video-mouse, ipmitool

Is there a way to provide to a new user "KVM access" using ipmitool or sol? There is a checkbox in User Management settings and I can check it manually, but I have a few hundreds of servers (Lenovo, Inspur, Huawei, Asus, Gigabyte) and it is going to be pin in an ass.

Comment: Probably tags confused you: KVM might mean "keyboard-video-mouse" or "kernel virtualization machine"; the tag you added is for the latter case, while the question seems to be about former one. So, if by KVM you mean VGA console, no. It is not in the IPMI specification and there is no generic method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does IPMI always include KVM?](https://serverfault.com/questions/340409/does-ipmi-always-include-kvm)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Went to invite bicycle)